# Some recipes fail after update to Yocto 2.0 "Jethro"

Tags: updates, yocto, recipe

I've just upgraded my Yocto Poky from "Daisy" to "Jethro" and now some recipes which used to work fine fail on the "do_install" task with similar error messages:

```
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf/qpdf/6.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.31232)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf/qpdf/6.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.31232
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| NOTE: make -j 8 DESTDIR=/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf/qpdf/6.0.0-r0/image install
| make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf/qpdf/6.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.31232)
ERROR: Task 2 (/home/g0hl1n/git/meta-mine/recipes-foss/qpdf/qpdf_6.0.0.bb, do_install) failed with exit code '1'
```

I think this comes somehow from the separation of the build directory, but my searches for an answer/solution weren't successful.
The recipe which produces the error message above is:

```
DESCRIPTION = "PDF transformation/inspection software"
HOMEPAGE = "http://qpdf.sourceforge.net"
LICENSE = "Artistic-2.0"
SECTION = ""
DEPENDS = "libpcre"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/archive/release-qpdf-${PV}.tar.gz"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://Artistic-2.0;md5=7806296b9fae874361e6fb10072b7ee3"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "a0601b0bc56d3f412fd3afecfce2721c"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "ce323ca692ddc6da31a90ef8a5f7fb7bc6c61c1c037e2eac14e5d0fcfe6a2797"

S="${WORKDIR}/${PN}-release-${PN}-${PV}"

inherit autotools gettext

# disable random file detection for cross-compile
EXTRA_OECONF = "--without-random"

PACKAGES =+ "libqpdf"

FILES_libqpdf = "${libdir}/libqpdf.so.*"
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the answer myself. (I should have done more research before posting here...)

The build fails because of a change in the `autotools` class in the Yocto 1.7 update.

> A separate build directory is now used by default: The autotools class has been changed to use a directory for building (B), which is
>   separate from the source directory (S). This is commonly referred to
>   as B != S, or an out-of-tree build.
>
> If the software being built is already capable of building in a
>   directory separate from the source, you do not need to do anything.
>   However, if the software is not capable of being built in this manner,
>   you will need to either patch the software so that it can build
>   separately, or you will need to change the recipe to inherit the
>   autotools-brokensep class instead of the autotools or autotools_stage
>   classes. [1]

So changing from `inherit autotools` to `inherit autotools-brokensep` fixed the problem with the qpdf build.

[1] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#migration-1.7-autotools-class-changes